# Writing a Batch Program from Local System Variables Using the Set Command

Tags: batch-file

I'm required to write a program that displays the computer name, username, and path to user files. All of these should be taken from local system variables. It's been hinted that I'm supposed to use the `set` command, however, I'm not sure how to use the set command in this situation... I had assumed that I could just use `echo %COMPUTERNAME%` etc. How can I implement the set command?

Comment: What happens when you enter `Set` at the Command prompt? I'm guessing that the hint was so that you could use the output, to help you with your required commands, not that you need to use `Set` to output them, _which you could technically also do_.

Comment: Oh my god. You're definitely right. I didn't even consider what the set command did. Thank you so much for clearing up my misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem! Also take a look at what happens if you enter `Set ComputerName` at the prompt, then consider running this simple `For` loop at the prompt too, `for %a in (computername,username,userprofile) do @set %a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the hint about the `Set` command was so that you could use the output of it to help you identify the local system variables to use in your batch file, not that you need to use `Set` to output them.

When you enter `Set` at the Command prompt you'll get output showing you each of the defined system variables.

Additionally, if you enter `Set ComputerName` at the prompt, you should get output showing you all variables which begin with  the string `ComputerName`.

So based on the output of the `Set` command you could `Echo`, your three variables from a batch file like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo %ComputerName%
Echo %UserName%
Echo %UserProfile%
```

You could also include the variables with their values:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo %%ComputerName%%=%ComputerName%
Echo %%UserName%%=%UserName%
Echo %%UserProfile%%=%UserProfile%
```

You could also consider running a simple `For` loop in your batch file to show the same  content using the `Set` command directly:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (ComputerName,UserName,UserProfile) Do Set %%A
Pause
```

Or you could return just their values using `Set` and `Echo` from nested `For` loops:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (ComputerName,UserName,UserProfile) Do (
    For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%B In ('Set %%A') Do Echo %%C)
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

to take the question very literal ("display the computer name ... using `set` command"):

```
set computername
set username
set userprofile
```

output like:

```
COMPUTERNAME=Elon-PC
USERNAME=Muscrat
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Muskrat
```

(Compo already has this method in his answer, but I guess using the `for` command is over the boundaries of the current state of your course)

(Note: for practical use, in most cases Compo's answer (using variables) is better, because in practice, you will probably *do* something with the values, not "just" *show* them, but this literally answers your question)

Comment: This is great to know, too. This was more along the lines of what I was thinking. Thank you for your answer, too!